# Windows 2008 Best Raid Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid

I have 4 2TB hard drives and I was thinking about using Raid 10. This would give me 4TB correct? My next question is would it be easy to add more hard drives to the raid array. For example if I bought another hard drive can I add it to the array without backing up any data?

Basically I want to be able to start off with 4TB and when the space becomes full add more space as needed. If this isn't possible with Raid 10, is it possible with any Raid configuration.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is entirely dependent on your RAID controller.**

Any halfway decent RAID controller will allow you to add disks and grow an existing array. I suggest you consult the manual for your server's RAID controller - It should spell out whether or not this is supported in no uncertain terms.

Assuming that the controller supports this, you can easily extend the volume in Windows using `diskmgmt.msc` afterwards.

Comment: Emphasis on checking the controller here, RAID10 often requires two disks to be added at a time to maintain the multiple of 2.  Either way this varies depending on the controller.